# Differentiability of $ f(x) = \frac1{\lfloor1/x\rfloor} $ at $ x = 0 $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

How can I determine if the following function is differentiable at $x=0$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\dfrac1{\lfloor1/x\rfloor} &\text{for } x \neq 0, \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

We have

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac1{x\cdot \lfloor1/x\rfloor}$$

How can I decide if this limit exists or not?

Comment: The expression for the positive limit is undefined for any points in a sequence converging to $0$ (once in a small enough neighbourhood). So the limit can't exist.

Comment: If I take $x=\frac1n$ I'll get $\frac{n}{floor(n)}$ Still I am unable to figure out how to say that this limit is not existing as $n\to \infty$

Comment: I'm so sorry I was thinking of it as the floor of $x$, not $\frac{1}{x}$. What I said is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

When  $x$ tends to $0$, for each value $x\le 1$, there exists an integer $n>0$ such that $$\frac1{n+1}<x\le \frac1n.$$